# jQuery UI Tabs: No close button if there is only one tab?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I've created a tab group where the user can add and close tabs, following the [example](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#manipulation) at jQuery UI.

It works fine, but I need to make it so that if there is only one tab, you can't close it. Basically the same functionality as tabs in Safari - the first tab only has a close button when there is more than one.

I figure it's something along the lines of this:

```
if (tabNumber < 2) {
  $("#nav-tabs").tabs(".ui-icon-close").hide();
}
```

But not quite. How do I do that?

Any help is mucho appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this issue by using CSS [`:only-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:only-child) psuedoselector:

```
.ui-tabs-nav li:only-child span.ui-icon-close{
  display:none !important;
}
```

This will hide the close button if there is only one tab. No JS! :)

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bkk3pfjm/)

Comment: So this won't work in my situation either, because the add-tab button is inside the ul. It's the only place I could put it to get it to align next to the tabs as new tabs are added. So my code looks like this: 
`<ul class="nav-tab-menu">
    <li><a href="views/dashboard.htm" class="ui-icon-dashboard">Dashboard</a><span class="ui-icon-close" role="presentation"><span class='sr'>Remove Tab</span></span></li>
    <span class="add-tab ui-icon-tab-add" href="views/empty.htm"><span class="sr">New Tab</span></span>
  </ul>` Any way to target just the li's?

Comment: Got it. Just replaced "only-child" with "only-of-type" and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

My first instinct was to find a inbuilt solution. But since we are adding the close button manually we should handle when its showed too. so my solution is also along what you mentioned. I just modified the example given [here](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#manipulation). I made a custom refresh function like this

```
function refresh(t){
  tabCount = $("#tabs li")
  console.log(tabCount.length)
  if(tabCount.length == 1){
    $('.ui-icon-close').hide()
  }
  else{
    $('.ui-icon-close').show()
  }
  t.tabs( "refresh" )
}
```

and replace all refresh calls to this

```
refresh(tabs)
```

I made a working example [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FesJn)
I hope it gets you started

Comment: Thanks shakirthow. Unfortunately, it looks like it won't work with my live one (which is a bit more complicated than the example), and I'm not sure why:

[link]http://bushidodesigns.net/avst